# Decomposing table into BCNF that preserves dependencies

Tags: normalization, denormalization

I have a relation like

```
R(A,B,C)
```

and dependencies like

```
A->B , B->C , A->C
```

I think the relation is in 2NF as candidate key is `A`. AFAIK when there is only one candidate key then the relation is in 2NF. So to decompose it into 3NF I broke the relation into

```
R1(A,B) R2(B,C)
```

and dependencies are

```
{A->B} and {B->C}
```

This is also in BCNF but `A->C` isn't preserved. So do I have to make another relation as `R3(A,C)` with `A->C` dependency?